# sed: how to match lines starting with word but not ending with another word

Tags: sed

suppose I want to add the word "end" to each line starting with "start". However if the word "end" is already at the end of the line; no need to add it again. So how do I get from:

```
start line 1
start line 2 end
another line 3
start line 4
```

to

```
start line 1 end
start line 2 end
another line 3
start line 4 end
```

This command matches lines starting with "start", but does not exclude the lines ending with "end". How can I get a regex that does both in one line?

```
sed 's/\(^start.*\)/\1 end/g'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```
sed -i '/ end$/! s/^start .*$/& end/' testfile
```

---

`-i` option, allows to modify the file *in place*

`/ end$/!` - allows performing the *next* action(substitution) only for those lines which don't end with `' end'` word

`s/^start .*$/& end/` - performs the replacement only for those lines which start with `start` word

---

If you admit the possibilities of using another good alternatives for your case, `awk` could be one of them:

```
awk '{print ($1 == "start" && $(NF) != "end") ? $0" end" : $0}' testfile
```

`$1` - points to the first field

`$(NF)` - points to the last field

Comment: Or maybe without capturing group : `sed '/ end$/!s/^start.*/& end/' testfile`